# Evaluation order of function arguments in Clojure

Tags: clojure

Does Clojure specify the order of evaluation of function arguments?

I.e. When I call a function in Clojure:

```
(my-func (fun1 arg1) (fun2 arg2) (fun3 arg3))
```

Is the order of evaluation of `fun1`, `fun2`, and `fun3` defined?

I understand that Java defines the order of evaluation of function arguments as left to right, but I can imagine a functional language like Clojure being more relaxed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Order of evaluation is left to right. See http://clojure.org/evaluation

> Both the operator and the operands
>   (if any) are evaluated, from left to
>   right.

Comment: It's interesting from that link to see that `((fun1 arg) (fun2 arg) (fun3 arg))` will cause all `funN` functions to be called, prior to the result of `(fun1 arg)` being cast to a function type (which it might not be).

Answer (score 10):

Left to right, but inside out as well (fun1 (fun2 arg2)).

I think that in general for a functional language, you would want to avoid the situation where (fun1 arg1) influences (fun2 arg2) or (fun3 arg3). (fun1 arg1) ideally would return a value without altering the state of existing data structures in your program.

Therefore, depending on how close you keep to a functional programming style, the left-to-right order of evaluation is unimportant.

see http://clojure.org/state

Comment: +1 for the insight that if your program is written in good FP style, it shouldn't matter....

Answer (score 1):

(my-func (fun1 arg1) (fun2 arg2) (fun3 arg3))

my-func has arity of 3. The result of (fun1 arg1) will be passed as the first argument to my-func. Etc. Then my-func will be executed.

Therefore the order of evaluation of arguments to my-func does not matter at all.

If you have side-effects, then, well, hmmmm... But this answer does not change. The order does not matter.

Cheers -