# Does the order of function calls inside a Clojure map guarantee runtime order processing?

Tags: clojure

I'm working on the following function:

```
(defn process-request [request]
  (if (not (db/empty?))
    {:person (db/get-person!) :violations (:violations (process-violations request))}
    {:person {} :violations ["no-person"]}))
```

I need the `process-violations` function to only be called if the db is not empty. That's why it's in the `if` block.

However, I also need it to be called **before** the `db/get-person!` function. Otherwise, the value will be outdated.

So I wonder:

- How would I do that?
- And anyway, is the order of values in a map enough to guarantee that a function will always be called before another?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, maps are not ordered. For small literal maps it will probably work, but you should not rely on it, and for larger maps it indeed does fail:

```
user=> {0 (println 0) 1 (println 1) 2 (println 2) 3 (println 3) 4 (println 4) 5 (println 5) 6 (println 6) 7 (println 7) 8 (println 8) 9 (println 9)}
0
7
1
4
6
3
2
9
5
8
{0 nil, 7 nil, 1 nil, 4 nil, 6 nil, 3 nil, 2 nil, 9 nil, 5 nil, 8 nil}
```

But it is always easy to force ordering by using `let` bindings, which are evalauted, in order, before the `let` body.

```
(let [person (db/get-person!)]
  {:person person :violations ...})
```

Comment: In addition to the approach of using `let` to have arguments evaluated in order, calling the `hash-map` or `array-map` function might also work: `(hash-map 0 (println 0) 1 (println 1))`. The evaluation order is left to right (https://stackoverflow.com/a/4815462/1008794).

Answer (score 2):

The reader will read the map in the code into a map, about which you should make no ordering assumptions, so do not rely on the evaluation order of those values. (In reality, it's an array map, and it probably is evaluated in the same order as defined lexically, but you should not rely on that.)

```
(defn process-request [request]
  (if (not (db/empty?))
    (let [violations (:violations (process-violations request))
          person (db/get-person!)]
      {:person person :violations violations})
    {:person {} :violations ["no-person"]}))
```

would be safer.